# What could be the SQL injection string for following query?

Tags: sql-injection

We are using a query as follows:

```
FROM users u INNER JOIN FETCH u.roles where u.password='" + password + "'" + " AND u.username='" + username + "'";
```

To prevent sql-injection, we are using regular expression to filter "username" and only allow whitelist of characters such as "**^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$**" and for "password" field we are using the check such as,

```
 if(password.indexOf("'") != -1) { Sql injection attack }
```

Is there any ways for attackers to bypass the checks we have used to launch successful sql-injection attack?

We are using MySql v5.1

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just use one of the recognized solutions to the problem of SQL injection, such as prepared statements, an ORM, or stored procedures? Much easier than trying to whitelist "bad" characters.

Comment: Why are you jumping through all these hoops just to avoid properly paramterising your query?

Comment: Incidentally, because you have an INNER JOIN, a user with no roles but a valid password will be treated by your query exactly the same way as a user who's entered their password wrongly...

Comment: Rather than writing and testing code to clean your input, use parametrized queries so that you don't have to write any new code to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as it seems the moderators don't approve of me telling you to improve your code, the answer is simply "Yes, there is a flaw in the above code".

Comment: @podilska: could you let me know the flaw in above code and how it could be exploited by an attacker?

Comment: The flaw in the above code is that you are building SQL statements with outside data.  You need to use parametrized queries so that your data and SQL are kept apart from each other.  http://bobby-tables.com/ has many examples of how to do parametrized queries, based on whatever language you're writing in.